# How to get a D3.js pie chart to render data dynamically from the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, pie-chart

I'm trying to make a pie chart using D3.js that changes once the submit button has been clicked on in the HTML form (asking for total count of females and males).

This is what I have so far for the JavaScript file:

```
// Data
function getTotalFemales() {
    let total = document.getElementById('totalFemales').value;
    totals.push(parseFloat(total));
}

function getTotalMales() {
    let total = document.getElementById('totalMales').value;
    totals.push(parseFloat(total));
}

let totals = [];

// Dataset
var dataset = [
    {label: 'Female Count', count: 1},
    {label: 'Male Count', count: 1}
];

function updateChart() {
    dataset.count.forEach(function(num)
        dataset.count = totals[num]
    });

    console.log(totals);
}
```

and this is the d3 part:

```
var path = pieChart.selectAll('path')
        .data(pie(dataset))
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        return color(d.data.label);
    });
```

Any idea on how I can get the count property in the dataset array to change depending on the user's form values?

Comment: Would help if you created a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Take the input values and directly put them into the dataset. I don't see the need for the totals array.

And set the properties of the dataset array of objects,

```
  var dataset = [
    {label: 'Female Count', count: 1},
    {label: 'Male Count', count: 1}
];

    function getTotals() {
        dataset[0].count = document.getElementById('totalFemales').value;
        dataset[1].count = document.getElementById('totalMales').value;
    }
```